# Defining the range in nested loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to better my understanding of nested loops so that I can make star patterns. However while experimenting I came across something that completely confused me.

Here to print out 1-3 exacty 3 times using the inner loop of a nested loop works completely fine.

'''

```
for outer in range(1,4):
    for inner in range(1,4):
        print(f"O: {outer}, I {inner}")
```

OUTPUT

```
O: 1, I 1
O: 1, I 2
O: 1, I 3
O: 2, I 1
O: 2, I 2
O: 2, I 3
O: 3, I 1
O: 3, I 2
O: 3, I 3
```

However if I want to accomplish the same thing but this time I make the range of the inner loop the range of the outer loop, then i get this:

```
for outer in range(1, 4):
        for inner in range(1, outer+1):
            print(f"O: {outer}, I: {inner}")
```

```
O: 1, I: 1
O: 2, I: 1
O: 2, I: 2
O: 3, I: 1
O: 3, I: 2
O: 3, I: 3
```

Does anyone know why? Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect should happen? Are you confusing `outer` with something else? You print the value of `outer` ... connect the dots. Also you should look into using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the enumerator in this process.
When you define your for loop as:

```
for outer in range(x, x):
```

outer is the enumerated value, not the explicit range you have predefined.
I would suggest using a separate integer value (or equivalent) for this operation.
For example

```
int upperRange = 4
for outer in range(1, upperRange ):
    for inner in range(1, upperRange +1):
        print(f"O: {outer}, I: {inner}")
```

i hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`outer` changes on each iteration. You likely want to define a variable or use a function argument to use the same bounds for both ranges.

```
def test(n):
  for outer in range(1, n):
    for inner in range(1, n):
      print(f"O: {outer}, I: {inner}")
```